# query to create a subtype with no unique parameters

Tags: sql-server, relational-database, create-table, subtype

Lets say I have a Supertype entity called Box and three subtypes BlackBox, WhiteBox, GrayBox. Blackbox and WhiteBox have no parameters of their own. Box has BoxCode as primary key and BlackBox has a BLBoxCode as its pk in my relational diagram.

How do I create the table for BlackBox in MS SQL ? Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The same column should be both primary key and foreign key to the immediate supertype.

```
CREATE TABLE BlackBox
(
    box_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY REFERENCES Box (box_id),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Is this query okay ?
CREATE TABLE BlackBox_T
(BlackBoxCode int not null,
CONSTRAINT BlackBox_PK PRIMARY KEY (BoxCode),
CONSTRAINT BlackBox_FK FOREIGN KEY (BlackBoxCode) REFERENCES Box_T (BoxCode))

Comment: @user1440230 - Yes and you get extra points for giving specific names to all the constraints.  That makes it much easier to alter them later.

Comment: How does it make it easier to alter them later ? I am new, so please excuse my newbie doubts.

Comment: @user1440230 - If you don't give the constraint a name (as in my simplistic syntax), SQL Server will generate a name, that will end in randomly assigned letters (a possibly different name on every box where you apply the script).  Unless you are managing only a single database in the whole world (not even a test database), it is a really tedious job to detect the name later, when you need to do some modification to the constraint automatically.